# Excel Formula change and remove

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

The numbers on the form are for two different references. 2015-##### (five digits after year) is the way it will be entered. When the user enters that I would like to enter in another cell the result E15-#### (Replace first two digits in year with "E" and remove first digit after dash. Thank you.

Comment: Describe the problem better.  As written, `=IF(A1="2015-01234","E15-1234")` is technically a valid solution, but I doubt that's what you intended.

Comment: The numbers on the form are for two different references. 2015-##### (five digits after year) is the way it will be entered. When the user enters that I would like to enter in another cell the result E15-#### (Replace first two digits in year with "E" and remove first digit after dash. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula `="E"&MID(A1,3,3)&RIGHT(A1,4)` will do what you requested. It does assume that all user entries are as you described as in a four digit year, a dash, and a five digit extension.